# How can I use the word breaker from Microsoft SQL Server 2005 in my stand-alone C# program

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, com-interop, stemming, wordbreaker

I am writing a program which will query a full text search index on Microsoft SQL Server 2005. The data being indexed are large blobs of text (multiple lines).

I need to extract only those lines of text which contain the search words for display with the results.

I therefore need to use the Sql Server word breaker and stemmer to determine if each line of text from the blob matches the search string, as I understand the standard word breaker and stemmer in Windows search uses a different algorithm.

I thought if I copied the two dlls (infosoft and langwrbk) from a SQL Server installation to the machine on which I am running my program, and ran regsvr32 on them, they would be installed in the registry, and I would be able to use them.

No such luck - running regsvr32 does not seem to add anything to the registry at all!

I have code which does the job with the word breaker and stemmer that comes with Windows, and it works, but I'm worried about the differences (which I have seen complained about in other posts here).

Comment: I have just tried the code at https://gist.github.com/1568627 kindly provided by http://stackoverflow.com/users/410496/john-jeffery of this parish. I just get an error  80004005 (native error 193) when trying to load the Sql Server langwbrk and infosoft dlls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the code at [COM without registering](http://gist.github.com/1568627) kindly provided by [john-jeffery](https://stackoverflow.com/users/410496/john-jeffery) of this parish.

I had problems originally, until I realised the DLLs I was using were 64-bit, and the code I was using it from was 32-bit. Once I made the calling code 64-bit, everything worked. (I imagine I could have taken the DLLs from a 32-bit version of Sql Server if I wanted to stay 32-bit).

I have posted a test LinqPad script which uses both word breaker and stemmer to [my blog](http://trumphurst.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/using-word-breaker-from-microsoft-sql.html), in case there is anyone else out there who wants to do the same thing.